# How do I type a floating point infinity literal in python

Tags: python, floating-point, portability, numerical

How do I type a floating point infinity literal in python?

I have heard

```
 inf = float('inf')
```

is non portable.  Thus, I have had the following recommended:

```
 inf = 1e400
```

Is either of these standard, or portable?  What is best practice?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In [python 2.6](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html) it is portable if the CPU supports it

> The float() function will now turn the
>   string nan into an IEEE 754 Not A
>   Number value, and +inf and -inf into
>   positive or negative infinity. This
>   works on any platform with IEEE 754
>   semantics.

Comment: @fmark:  Good luck finding a platform that Python runs on but that doesn't have IEEE 754 semantics.   In theory, `float('inf')` should raise `ValueError` on these platforms, but to my knowledge this behaviour has never been tested, because Python (well, recent versions of Python, at least) has yet to meet such a platform.  In practice don't worry about it.

Answer (score 16):

`float('inf')` is non portable as in not portable back to Python 2.5 when the string output varies between platforms. From 2.6 and onwards `float('inf')` is guaranteed to work on IEEE-754-compliance platforms (ref: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0754/).

(And the recommendation seems to be in the range 1e30000, not just 1e400.)

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps you could do something like this

```
try:
    inf = float('inf')
except:  # check for a particular exception here?
    inf = 1e30000
```

Comment: +1.  `float('inf')` is definitely to be preferred, in general.  It's even possible that 'inf = 1e30000` might start raising `OverflowError` instead of producing an infinity in some future version of Python.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Python 3.6, you can use [math.inf](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.inf).

```
import math
math.inf
```